# Why is the 24-cell (also called Icositetrachoron or Hyperdiamond) the unique regular convex polychoron which has no direct three-dimensional analog?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, polytopes, platonic-solids

> The 24-cell is self-dual, and is the unique regular convex polychoron which has no direct three-dimensional analog.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/24-Cell.html

I don't understand why that is true. Why isn't his three-dimensional analog the octahedron (which is a Platonic solid)?

Edit : Bump.

Comment: In short, because there's _also_ a 4-dimensional analog of the octahedron; the 4-dimensional cross-polytope (which is dual to the hypercube).  If the 24-cell were the analog of the octahedron, it wouldn't be self-dual.

Comment: I'd like to argue that the 24-cell does have an analogue in 3 dimensions, the rhombic dodecahedron.  Both are constructed by taking the convex hull of the vertices of a cube and of an appropriately sized cross polytope (i.e. an octahedron).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 5 "regular" convex polytopes in 3-dimensions but there are 6 "regular" convex polytopes in 4-dimensions. In all higher dimensions than 4, there are only three "regular" convex polytopes. These are the analogues of the regular tetrahedron, the regular cube, and the regular octahedron. Here are two places  which might help you understand what is going on here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regular_polytopes#Four-dimensional_regular_polytopes and http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/platonic.html

Comment: This seems to be a generally-accepted answer, and I can see why the 24-cell is not considered to have a direct analog in 3 dimensions; what's not so clear to me is why people think the 120-cell and 600-cell _do_ have direct analogs.